# When bibtex does not find bibdata inside aux file, with code

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am receiving the following error message

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2014)
The top-level auxiliary file: thesis.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file thesis.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file thesis.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
```

I am wonderinf why that could be. I am using

```
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
```

for my bibliography and the following commands to create it

```
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\hspace*{\labelwidth}}
\apptocmd{\NAT@thebibliography}{\setlength\itemindent{-14pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

\bibliography{/Users/myname/Dropbox/Bibliography/bibo}
```

and the strange thing is that it had been working a few hrs. ago. I am not sure what changed.

Does someone know what could the problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: presumably latex never reached `\bibliography{/Users/myname/Dropbox/Bibliography/bibo}` a misplaced `\end{document}` for example would do that. Without any sample code, impossible to guess really.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that did the trick! All it took was an experienced hand looking at my error output. Given this issue had confounded someone else as well, I'd be happy to accept this as an answer when you make it one David. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Presumably latex never reached

```
\bibliography{/Users/myname/Dropbox/Bibliography/bibo}
```

a misplaced `\end{document}` for example would do that.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, I've been trying to figure out why my bibliography is missing for hours, alas, it was an additional `\end{document}`.

Comment: That's often the case, if one is using an `\input` or `\include` command, that is, there could be a duplicate `\end{document}` in the inputted or included file.